# Return array without first element with updated index (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array `let animals = ["cat", "dog", "elephant"]`

And I want to return a new array without first element, but when I use

```
let animalsWithoutCat = animals[1...animals.count - 1]
// or
let animalsWithoutCat = animals.dropFirst()
```

I get an array with `animals`' index, so `"dog"` is 1 and `"elephant"` is 2.

I want an array with updated index (started with 0). Fewer lines of code is preferred ))

Thanks for any help!

Comment: just use `Array(animals.dropFirst())` or use its indices when accessing its elements

Comment: I'm not quite getting your question. If you have an array say:
    let animals = ["cat", "dog", "elephant"]
And you do:
    animals.dropFirst()
You get a new array with the elements:
    ["dog", "elephant"]

Comment: @DiogoAntunes `animals.dropFirst()` result is an ArraySlice and there is no element at index  0

Comment: On that case, just use Array(animals.dropFirst()) ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you want is the `tail` of the array.

If you implement it in an extension like this

```
extension Array {

  var tail: Array {
    return Array(self.dropFirst())
  }

}
```

you can call it like this:

```
let animals = ["cat", "dog", "elephant"]
let animalsWithoutCat = animals.tail
```

If the array is empty `tail` is an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
let animals = ["cat", "dog", "elephant"]

var animalsWithoutCat = animals
animalsWithoutCat.removeFirst() // Removes first element ["dog", "elephant"]
```

**Or** us it as an extention:

```
extension Array {
func arrayWithoutFirstElement() -> Array {
    if count != 0 { // Check if Array is empty to prevent crash
        var newArray = Array(self)
        newArray.removeFirst()
        return newArray
    }
    return []
}
```

Simply call:

```
let animalsWithoutCat = animals.arrayWithoutFirstElement()
```